# Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : invalid RGB specification

Tags: r, gis, random-forest, image-classification, satellite-image

I want to construct a spectral profile for my bands, however I get the error "Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ". How do I go about solving this issue.The length(mycolors)==nrow(sp)

```
 #aggregate cl-column
sp <- aggregate( . ~ cl, data = trainingdata, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)

#Plot empty plot of the defined size
plot(0,
     ylim = c(min(sp[2:ncol(sp)]), max(sp[2:ncol(sp)])),
     xlim = c(1, ncol(trainingdata)-1),
     type = 'n',
     xlab = "Sentinel2A Bands",
     ylab = "Reflectance [% * 100]"
)

#Define colors for class representation - one color per class!
mycolors <- c("#ffbf00", "#bf9000", "#9d5b17", "#fce00", "#56b4e9", "#32410c", "ff0000", "#808080")

#Draw one line for each class
for(i in 1:nrow(sp)){
  print(i)
  lines(as.numeric(sp[i,-1]),
        lwd = 3,
        col = mycolors[i],
        
  )
}
```

Comment: Please share the relevant part of your code as text in your question, not as an image. Also, you can put `print(i)` inside the loop to see in which iteration the error occurs. I suspect you indexing goes beyond the vector with colors, e.g. indexing item 20 if there is no item 20. Is `length(mycolors)` equal to `nrow(sp)`?

Comment: Hi @Zoe, when I put 'print(i)'  I get: Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ and yes 'length(mycolors)' is equal to 'nrow(sp)'.

Comment: You have to add the `print(i)` inside the loop but after or before the `lines()`. Can you give the result of `as.numeric(sp[i,-1])` for `i = 1`? It seems like you are giving wrong coordinates or coordinates in a format R does not like...

Comment: @Zoe, when I add the `print(i)` it returns **1,2,3,4** and the error invalid RGB Specification. The results for `as.numeric(sp[1,-1])` are **0.03314167 0.05018750 0.06351667 0.14097500**

Comment: So your code fails in the fourth iteration. The fourth value in your color vector has 5 digits instead of 6, try replacing that color!